# Is it possible to convert form's data to file before sending to server using Javascript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-post

I have a Html form. I want to get the file containing posted form's data instead of sending raw posted data to the server.

In brief, I want to decrypt the form's data client side (before sending to the server). Therefore, in man-in-the-middle scenario, listener could not understand it.

Step one should be serializing form's data on Submit button's click event. Then, I can decrypt data with a private key (which my client has it) and then send it to the server.

First of all, I want to know if sending a file containing encrypted data is more safe than posting an encrypted posted data or not? And if yes, is it possible?!

Edited: I can't use SSL!

Comment: Securing data in form posts is what SSL is for. There's absolutely no point in trying to do it yourself in JavaScript.

Comment: @Pointy, except cases there SSL isn't applicable (law/gov enforcement? but I believe encryption in that case became an issue on it's own)

Comment: @JuicyScripter huh??  Plenty of government sites use SSL.

Comment: @JuicyScripter I can't use SSL.

Comment: I'm actually think about opposite side (like this http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10992/encryption-laws-in-iran)

Comment: @Pointy, the OP is in Iran and usage of SSL wouldn't make data secure from government.

Comment: Oh well if your government kindly insists that you don't use SSL, they would probably also kindly insist you don't use any other encryption technique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what SSL is for. You could try hashing the data using JS but eventually you will find that the password/passphrase that is necessary for encryption, will need to be passed to the javascript. Since JS runs on the client and is not precompiled your passphrase will be plain-text in the file => not very secure. So unless you find a way to somehow pass a passphrase in a secure way, you would have to go with SSL

Answer (score 1):

You could override the functionality of the "submit" button to instead call a Javascript function that could then pull the values out of the form, modify them any way that you want (e.g. encrypt them), and then post them to the server with an AJAX call instead of the normal form POST/GET action.

Comment: Thanks, and how can I put the data in a file and then post them to server? Is it possible?

Comment: Does it have to be in a file "attachment"? You could just format the data any way you want with javascript and then send it to the server through $.post()

Comment: Yes, I want to send it in attachment.